# I want to pass the header value in methods

Tags: karate

Scenario : I need to verify the logs response on server on the basis of Tracking-Id.
I had passed the tracking-id using 'header.js' file, here i define metod which get the unique UUID for every request and passed in header.
Now I need that header value to passed in some method to get logs only for specific Tracking-Id
Is there any way to achieve this in karate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `karate.set('someVarName', uuidValue)` in JS and then back in the feature you will be able to: `* print someVarName`.

EDIT: please see this commit for an example: [link](https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/5b8b4a7ce67ea6d8ee7ef842058fc0dca1c4a044)

Comment: I define the below code in my header.js file:           function headers() {

    var token = java.util.UUID.randomUUID();


    return {
       
        'X-Request-Tracking-Id':token,
    };
    karate.set('TrackingID',token);
}                                                                      
 But still not able to get the value of 'TrackingId' in feature file. Can you share example for same

Comment: I have raised a concern here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/636